# Why is a commit not showing on the github repo but I can provide a working link to said commit?

Tags: github

So I have been trying to figure out why [this commit](https://github.com/mwoolweaver/tweetStats/commit/a0e70c7b7aba44e62c69edbff022a6d6452f7ee6) is not showing anywhere?

Comment: Did you actually push it to a *branch*? Or have you pushed a rewritten version of that commit (e.g. after a rebase)? How did it get there?

Comment: A contribution was made by someone and the asked if it broke anything for as it worked fine for them but I can’t seem to actually test it as git shows nothing to pull...

Comment: Nor does it show up on any other branch in the repo...

Comment: It might not be on a branch, they're usually referred to as "orphaned" commits.

Comment: It’s strange that it happened that way... considering it was made via web browser... not sure how to go about adding the commit and the person still get credit.. maybe I’ll just have them make the commit again and ensure it’s in the right place...

Comment: Can you provide the steps to reproduce this? In other words, just provide a [mcve]. However, I'm hesitant whether questions about some third-party service are correctly placed here. As the Github service contact instead, I'd say.

Comment: The situation is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59019763/4692301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to edit a file in someone else's repository through the GitHub web UI, it automatically creates a fork of that repo in your account and generates a `patch-{n}` branch for the commit to be on. This is complicated slightly by the fact that the author of the commit to which you refer is actually the owner of the repo from which you forked yours, although theirs has a different name. You can see the commit `a0e70c7` in the `patch-3` branch on their original repo: https://github.com/DarthKeizer/Pi-Hole-stats-tweeter/commits/patch-3.

Comment: Thank you for this!! Not sure how I was managing to over look that...